# Trying to assign a multidimensional array into a struct

Tags: c, arrays

I'm having trouble trying to assign a md array into a struct md array.
Basically:

```
typdef struct {
  int num;
  char array[30][80];
} Vars;
```

then in main I did some parsing to make an array of strings, which is aclled strArray and is also [30][80]. However, when I try to do this

```
char strArray[30][80] = {"example", "text"};
Vars *vars = (Vars *) malloc(sizeof(Vars);
vars->array = strArray;
```

I keep getting an error

```
error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[30][80]’ from type ‘char (*)[80]’
```

I've tried to do it even string by string in a for loop, but keep getting errors. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You didn't post the `strArray` declaration, and you can't assign to arrays. And [Don't cast the result of `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: You can't assign dynamic memory to a pointer of statically allocated array. Also you're missing a bracket after sizeof(Vars) when you allocate. You should also give us a declaration of strArray.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you are trying to do, but you can't assign to arrays.

What you probably want is

```
#include <string.h>

size_t i;

for (i = 0 ; i < 80 ; i++)
    strcpy(vars->array[i], strArray[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Vars vars = (Vars *) malloc(sizeof(Vars);` doesn't even compile. Hopefully you meant something like:

```
Vars *vars = malloc( sizeof *vars );
```

Now, arrays cannot be assigned by value. To make a copy of the array you will have to use functions which can cope with arrays. One way would be:

```
STATIC_ASSERT( sizeof vars->array == sizeof strArray );
memcpy(&vars->array, &strArray, sizeof strArray);
```

---

If you do not really want to copy the data then consider having `Vars` contain a pointer instead of an array; then you can just make that point at `strArray`. The type would be `char (*array)[80];`.

Another option would be for `strArray` to actually be a `Vars` struct (even if you don't use `num`); then you can just use structure assignment to do the copying.